Remote dektopGUI login to rebooted ubuntu PC/desktop
Hypothetical but more like an actual problem***: Ubuntu desktop reboots - I have BIOS setup to go back to "on" when the power returns - this part works.  The problem is that the machine does display the desktop/gui "log in" screen but neither the built in remote desktop client (in another Ubuntu pc) will work unless the machine in question has a user logged on to it already.  x2go does not work either unless, once again, a user is already logged on to it.  If I have someone log on to the pc both of the previous methods work.
A long time ago I got google remote desktop to work but I do not want to depend on google (plus it did stop working with some updates and I had to ssh to the machine, restart the service and then I could log on to the Ubuntu/gui).  I like a solution I can more predictably control.  Currently I can log on to it via ssh but that is not what I am looking for, more like a remote session for users other than me who will not be able to do anything with ssh.  Anyone has been able to achieve this?
The behavior I am looking for is similar to how google remote desktop behaves on windows.  I can have a freshly rebooted windows 10/11 machine and I can turn on google remote desktop and see the log in screen and sign in and work.  Windows remote desktop offers a similar behavior which is proffered as it does not allow local users to disturb the remote session.
Anyone has achieved this or something similar they can point me to so I can work it out?
Thank you
*** Edit***
Someone pointed out this is not a site for hypothetical questions.
In my defense it was a way I thought I could ask.  This is ONE of the possibilities and why I limited to a hypothetical.  Power goes out where I live occasionally.  There are brown outs which cause problems or dips in power.  Also, in case someone turns off my PC I can in fact use WOL to turn it on but it all goes back to the same problem.  Is there a way to log on to a recently rebooted PC which is display in the log in screen?
I am sorry if someone misunderstood and I realize I should not say hypothetical.

In Settings -> Users you can set a toggle Automatic Login for a user. Of course it's insecure but may be o.k. for your purposes? It won't unlock the keyring but will logon.

Not a site for hypothetical. This is a question and answer site. Maybe find a forum site for this?

@codlord - thanks.  While this would fix the log in problem I think it weakens security.  I did consider this in the past but d it would not be a good security practice.  I am opting for creating an additional VM but since it is for others to use I want to make it available with a keyboard and mouse for the local users as well.  Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Good morning, I was able to partly achieve what I am looking to do.
I am posting this content in hopes it helps someone looking for a similar solution to a this remote desktop/access problem.  After further readings and comments/responses from others in other forums, it seem some desktop environments have some compatibility problems.  It was suggested to install LXDE (I used the distribution before) so I ran: "sudo apt install lxde"
After loading it I can log on to the PC even when there is no user logged in.  I am now working on getting the size of all the components to look better as the proportions are really bad and very difficult to use.
I do not know which are the desktop environments which have the compatibility issue.  I just tried it on PoP_OS and Ubuntu.  Both did not work but when I installed LXDE it worked with no user logged in.  I am guessing there will be some desktop environments which should work but you will have to try the one you are using to find out.  This worked for me and I hope it helps others.
